# VS Specify WinForm open order

Tags: winforms, debugging, visual-studio-2015

I have an already created project with plenty of WinForms and specified StartUp project.
I'm creating a new form in a different project and wanted to know if there is a proper way to set a specific form load order post debug start.
Is there a some kind of a configuration for that or some checkbox for that, or maybe I'm just asking a really trivial question with an obvious answer (which I didn't find on my own)?

I'm running this projects on Visual Studio Express 2015 Desktop.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Right click on the project, select Set as Startup Project?

Comment: For the whole solution a different project is necessary to be set as StartUp project. (the solution doesn't run if a different project is set as StartUp Project)

Comment: There is no "configuration", it is solely determined by the order in which your code calls the Show() method for these forms.

Comment: @HansPassant you can put that as an aswer - forgot about that. Thank you.

Comment: @ Hans Passant, thanks for sharing the solution, would you please post that comment as the answer? So it can be marked as the answer, and we could close this case:)